# How to doctors test for eye damage from a solar eclipse?

Tags: eye

Is pupil dilation required to test for any damage caused to the human eye by a solar eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Solar retinopathy commonly presents with blurred vision the day after gazing at an eclipse so the diagnosis can be made on the history. Other symptoms that might present include

> a central or paracentral scotoma, chromotopsia, metamorphopsia, photophobia, and headache

You don't need to dilate the pupil to examine the fovea, or to examine the macula, or to test visual acuity. However, pupillary dilatation might be of help in other investigations to confirm the diagnosis such as

> fundus autofluorescence (FAF), fluorescein angiography (FA), multifocal electroretinography (mfERG), and OCT

https://www.retinalphysician.com/issues/2013/october-2013/solar-retinopathy-etiology,-diagnosis,-and-treatm